# Using backbone template changes the jQuery class

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, parse-platform

When I use backbone (from parse.com) for my jQuery based page adding the template changes the appearance all together (First line of the code below)

```
<script type="text/template" id="login-template">
  <header id="header"></header>
  <div class="login">
    <form class="login-form">
      <br>
      <div class="error" style="display:none"></div>
      <input type="text" id="login-username" placeholder="Your email" />
      <input type="password" id="login-password" placeholder="Password" />
      <button>Log In</button>
    </form>
    <form class="signup-form">
      <br>
      <div class="error" style="display:none"></div>
      <input type="text" id="signup-username" placeholder="Your email" />
      <input type="password" id="signup-password" placeholder="Create a Password" />
      <button>Sign Up</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</script>
```

How it looks without first line of code above

[image]

How it looks with first line of code above

[image]

Comment: So where your Backbone code? Show Backbone views for that page

Answer (score 0):

It seems that after I make backbone templates, I can apply right classes to use jQuery CSS classes such as below. You just need to apply classes.

```
 <button class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Login</button>
```

instead of say using

```
<button>Sign Up</button>
```

see how login button has change appearance while still working in backbone template.
[image]